# Nginx caching long string query URLs

Tags: nginx

I am trying to cache this string query URL. Any idea can I cache this long URL in Nginx for an hour?

This URL contain three things 2 CSS files and one html file. I want to serve the first request from backend application and all other request for same string from Nginx.

```
http://x.x.x.x/uri/splash?TF=100%25&US=A&AR=D&TD=%2450&BR=T&TS=12515f542140&OR=%2410%2F100MB&DN=BAQGBgEEBwQAAw%3D%3D&ET=TD&BE=1332d9a&BN=CS&AL=2000
```

I am trying proxy_cache_key with following configurations .

```
set $string "$scheme://$ahost$request_uri$request_body $cookie_user";
proxy_cache_key $string;

if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 0;
}
```